# Unhandled rejection ReferenceError

Tags: testing, meteor, chimp.js

I have installed Meteor app from official tutorial and it works fine.

But get error when I try to run acceptance test. I run `meteor npm run chimp-watch`.

1. At the beginning Chrome browser is opened with  "data:," URL in
   address bar.
2. And there is error in terminal: "Unhandled rejection
   ReferenceError: Symbol is not defined".

I use Ubuntu and Node.js 6.1

`chimp watch` is `chimp --ddp=http://localhost:3000 --watch --mocha --path=tests`

Comment: Do you have any tests? Are you navigating to a url in your tests?